# Creating shp from txt files using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, create

I have a txt file like this:

```
Point
0 347172.2 4269952.7 60.9090909091
1 337172.8 4278952.4 85.7334909091
2 344572.3 4547952.2 123.909673091
3 347532.8 8777952.8 456.467809091
END
```

The third column are some values i want to have in my points.shp. I wrote this script but it doesn't seem to work, meaning it doesn't pass the specific values of the third column

```
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
# Set up inputs to tool
inTxt = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inSep = "."
strms = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
# Run tool
gp.CreateFeaturesFromTextFile(inTxt, inSep, strms, "#")
```

What should i add also? I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: When you run your code snippet as a test what values do you use for `inTxt` and `strms`?  What error or other symptom is seen when you run that?  Please use the **edit** button to provide a more detailed description of what you have tried and where you are stuck.  I wondered what your last line was about and found http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00pv0000000z000000 - linking to help associated with any lesser known functions that you are using can be a good way to help potential answerers help you.

Comment: i made a copy of this code and used it here. The result i get is actually the x,y coordinates but not the last value

Comment: According to the documentation for that sample tool it does not process more than the coordinates and "This tool has been deprecated" so I think you would be better using the approach advocated by @Aaron anyway.

Comment: so should i delete Point and End and make the rest of the data seem like for example for the first line:                     [('60.9090909091', ('347172.2', '4269952.7'))]  ??

Comment: can you provide an example of how you would use the newGeom.projectAs in this case to re-project the points from the input SR into OSGB (EPSG 27700)? I am writing more or less the same script but would like to take my input points (in WGS1984) and re-project them into OSGB (EPSG 27700) before inserting into a blank point shapefile. Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is one approach that utilizes an [Insert Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) to directly insert the coords into the SHAPE@XY slot.

```
import arcpy, os

# Read txt file
tmp = [line.split() for line in open(r'C:\temp\txtfile.txt')]

"""
Clean txt file and prepare for Insert Cursor
Needs to be in the following format for this example:
[('60.9090909091', ('347172.2', '4269952.7')),
 ('85.7334909091', ('337172.8', '4278952.4')),
 ('123.909673091', ('344572.3', '4547952.2')),
 ('456.467809091', ('347532.8', '8777952.8'))]
"""
row_values = []
for t in tmp:
    row_values.append((float(t[3]), (float(t[1]), float(t[2]))))

# Define the shapefile
shp = r'C:\temp\points.shp'

# Define spatial reference and create shapefile.  Factory code for NAD83 UTM 15N is used here
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(26915)
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management (out_path = os.path.dirname(shp), out_name = os.path.basename(shp), geometry_type = "POINT", spatial_reference = sr)
arcpy.AddField_management(shp, "Field1", "DOUBLE")

# Use InsertCursor to update rows
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(shp, ['Field1','SHAPE@XY'])

for row in row_values:
    cursor.insertRow(row)

# Clean up
del cursor
```

Comment: i made my line  from this                                    Point
0 347172.2 4269952.7 60.9090909091
END                                                                        to this                                                                      [('60.9090909091', ('347172.5', '4277952.5')) BUT i get a parsing error at line 16: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: yes i know, i am testing it for points but it doen't work amd returns an error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, for this to work you need to have your input data in the exact format that @Aaron specifies in the comment near the beginning of his code.  If your format is different then the code will need to be modified to work with it.

Comment: Please be aware that @Aaron has offered an approach, and that GIS SE uses a focussed Q&A format i.e. it does not offer a code writing/debugging service.

Comment: @por.bet I suspect that you need make sure your txt file does not contain the words "Point" and "END" at the beginning and end of the txt file. For this example, I copied your test data to a txt file (without "Point" and "END") and used that as the input data during testing.

Comment: so my data should be like that:                                           [('60.9090909091', ('347172.2', '4269952.7')),
 ('85.7334909091', ('337172.8', '4278952.4')),
 ('123.909673091', ('344572.3', '4547952.2')),
 ('456.467809091', ('347532.8', '8777952.8'))]

Answer (score 2):

Rather that getting the user to change the order/style of the points it would be best to change the code to suit the input.. I would imagine when you need to write a script to import points you'd have a lot of them..

I would try to split the lines using string.split and if I tried a few possible delimiters and still ended up with a list of 1 then skip the line:

```
Point <- skip, only one element
0 347172.2 4269952.7 60.9090909091 <- do this one, 4 elements
1 337172.8 4278952.4 85.7334909091 <- do this one, 4 elements
2 344572.3 4547952.2 123.909673091 <- do this one, 4 elements
3 347532.8 8777952.8 456.467809091 <- do this one, 4 elements
END <- skip, only one element
```

This is fairly easy to code for:

```
import os, sys, arcpy

InFile = sys.argv[1]
OutShp = sys.argv[2]
EPSG   = sys.argv[3]

try:
    SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(int(EPSG))# create a spatial reference from EPSG definition
except:
    arcpy.AddWarning(arcpy.GetMessages())
    arcpy.AddError("Unable to create spatial reference with code %s" % EPSG)
    sys.exit(0)

#break up OutShp to folder and name
OutFolder = os.path.dirname(OutShp)
OutName   = os.path.basename(OutShp)

# Create the output feature class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(OutFolder,OutName,"POINT",has_z="ENABLED",spatial_reference=SR)
# add fields to store the values
arcpy.AddField_management(OutShp,"PntID","INTEGER")
arcpy.AddField_management(OutShp,"Xcoord","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(OutShp,"Ycoord","DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(OutShp,"Zcoord","DOUBLE")

with open(InFile,'r') as srcFile:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(OutShp,["SHAPE@","PntID","Xcoord","Ycoord","Zcoord"]) as InsCur:
        for fileLine in srcFile:
            # split the line up into a list
            # 1 337172.8 4278952.4 85.7334909091 becomes [1,337172.8,4278952.4,85.7334909091]
            # try a few common delimiters: tab, space, comma, pipe..
            lSplit = fileLine.split("\t")
            if len(lSplit) == 1:
                lSplit = fileLine.split(" ")
            if len(lSplit) == 1:
                lSplit = fileLine.split(",")
            if len(lSplit) == 1:
                lSplit = fileLine.split("|")

            if len(lSplit) > 1:
                # more than just one word on the line
                pointsOK = True
                try:
                    ID     = int(lSplit[0])
                    Xcoord = float(lSplit[1])
                    Ycoord = float(lSplit[2])
                    Zcoord = float(lSplit[3])
                except:
                    arcpy.AddWarning("Unable to translate points")
                    pointsOK = False

                if pointsOK:
                    # create a point geometry from the 3 coordinates
                    newGeom  = arcpy.PointGeometry(arcpy.Point(Xcoord,Ycoord,Zcoord))
                    newGeom.spatial_reference = SR # set spatial reference
                    # you could project here using newGeom.projectAs(SpatialRef)
                    # if you needed them in a different spatial reference                        
                    InsCur.insertRow([newGeom,ID,Xcoord,Ycoord,Zcoord])# insert this point into the feature class
```

Arcpy insert cursor (arcpy.da.InsertCursor) does not allow "SHAPE@XYZ", but you can address this using "SHAPE@" and using a geometry object in arcpy. This is especially handy if you have the coordinates in a different spatial reference and need to project on the way in.